# wordpress add menu in admin dashboard on plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have created a folder in wp-content called finances.php.

When I activate the plugin, the menu and submenu is not showing.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Finances
Description: This plugin allows to upload the extract from the bank and will load this information in the database. It will then allow you to set some categories so that a summary can be shown for analysis.
Version: 0.1
*/


/**
 * New menu and sub menus
 */

function finances_options_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Finances',
        'Finances',
        'manage_options',
        'finances-admin-menu-main',
        'finances_admin_menu_main',
        'dashicons-media-code',
        1
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        'finances-admin-menu-main',
        'Upload File',
        'Upload',
        'manage_options',
        'finances-admin-menu-sub-upload',
        'finances_admin_menu_sub_upload'
    );
}

function remove_finances_options_page() {
    remove_menu_page('finances-admin-menu-sub-upload');
    remove_menu_page('finances-admin-menu-main');
}

/**
 * Activation and Deactivation hooks.
 */

function finances_activate() { 
    // Create the menu structure.
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'finances_options_page' );
}


function finances_deactivate() { 
    // Create the menu structure.
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_finances_options_page', 99 );
}

/**
 * Admin main menu page.
 */

function finances_admin_menu_main() {
    ?>   <h1>Finances Main</h1> <?php
}

function finances_admin_menu_sub_upload() {
    ?>   <h1>Finances Upload</h1> <?php
}

/**
 * Registration of hooks.
 */

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'finances_activate' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'finances_deactivate' );

?>
```

It is pretty simple but when I activate or deactivate the plugin, I get no errors, it says everything is fine. But I don't see the new menu and submenu on the left.

Also, I am logged in as admin so I should have the manage_options permission.

Comment: Activation and deactivation hooks are meant to setup and tear down your plugin in general, doing things like checking for license keys, adding/removing database tables, etc. They are only ever run once, and I would say that your average plugin doesn't really have a use for them. For WordPress, you don't "register a menu upon activation". Instead, once your plugin is activated, you want to just use the appropriate hooks and WordPress will call your code when needed. Your code should generally be something like this: https://3v4l.org/TtrGv#v8.2.5

Comment: You'll notice that code does nothing on activation, which is totally fine and very normal. On every page load in the admin area, WordPress fires the `admin_menu` hook and all plugins get to do there thing. In your case, `finances_options_page` will then be called along with the supporting functions as needed.